# How do I effectively use Batch Scripts?

Tags: batch-processing

I would like to create some batch scripts to move some files around.  But i was wondering if there are any good resources on how to do this? Do you just use Command Line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest level, a batch script is a text file with a `.bat` extension, and consists of the same commands you would enter at the command line, separated by carriage returns.

Thus, the file:

```
md C:\HelloWorld
```

Is a batch script that attempts to create the directory "HelloWorld" on your C: root.

Batch scripts can be much more complex, involving variables and flow control logic, but before you travel that road, you may want to investigate [powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419) and [WSH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit** Oops... fixed the link to powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just do command-line argument. But there are certain types of variables supported, and also command-line arguments to the batch file, which you can use.

http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm